# Data transfer using xbee and arduino

Tags: xbee

i have a portable device that consist of 
arduino leonardo board,xbee series 2 as router( AT mode ) and different sensors.This portable device acts as a remote device and can be used upon power up.
The other side, i have a host controller that consist of arduino uno board, arduinoxbee shield v1.1, and xbee series 2 as coordinator( AT mode ). This host controller is plug through USB into my PC.

The aim of my project is to send the sensor data from the portable device using xbee wirelessly over to my host controller and displaying out on the arduino serial monitor.
I've managed to configured the two xbees. But now, i'm unsure of how im going to transmit and receive the data. I need a transmitter and receiver program for both xbees that is connected to the arduino. Anyone can help please?

Comment: Are you using the XBees in change detect mode?

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple different options for how you can do this, but the simplest is to set up your sensor XBee either in change detect (IC) mode, or set a sample rate (IR). In either case you'll need to handle the RX Indicator frame at the controller, which will contain the sampled data.

I wrote a C# stack that can configure all this, but for what you're trying to do it would probably only be useful as a reference (https://github.com/jefffhaynes/XBee).